# Nested Route Firing from links, not from URL change

Tags: routes, ember.js

I am working on a basic ember.js application and am a little confused with some behavior. I have some routes that look like this:

```
this.resource('campaigns', { path: '/campaigns'}, function() {

    this.route('new', { path: '/new' });
    this.route('campaign', { path: '/:campaign_id' });

});

App.CampaignsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

model: function() {

    App.Keyword.find();
    return App.Campaign.find();

},

renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {

    this.render({outlet: 'page'});

}

});

App.CampaignsCampaignRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

model: function(params) {
    alert("Model Firing");
    console.log(params.campaign_id);
    return App.Campaign.find(params.campaign_id);
},
renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render({outlet: 'page'});
    alert("Template Firing");
}
```

});

...and a view that looks like this:

```
App.CampaignsCampaignView = Em.View.extend({

templateName: 'templates/campaigns/campaign',

});
```

...and a main template that looks like this:

```
<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- =================== APP HEADER =================== -->
<!-- ================================================== -->

{{ view App.HeaderView }}

<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- ======================= APP ====================== -->
<!-- ================================================== -->

<div id="app" class="">

<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- ==================== SIDEBAR ===================== -->
<!-- ================================================== -->

<div id="sidebar">

    {{ view App.NavigationView }}

    {{ view App.StarredCampaignsView }}

</div>

<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- ====================== STAGE ===================== -->
<!-- ================================================== -->

<div id="stage" class="">

    <!-- ================================================== -->
    <!-- ================= STAGE SIDEBAR ================== -->
    <!-- ================================================== -->

        <div id="stage-sidebar" class="">

        {{ view App.StageSidebarView }}

    </div>

    <!-- ================================================== -->
    <!-- ====================== PAGE ====================== -->
    <!-- ================================================== -->

    <div id="page" class="">

        {{ outlet page }}

    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

As you can see there are 2 very simple alerts in the CampaignsCampaign route just to let me know what is being activated.

So, /#/campaigns returns a list of campaigns, /#/campaigns/new returns a creation page and /#/campaigns/:campaign_id should display a single campaign and its details.

This all works perfectly from inside the system. When you click a campaign from the /#/campaigns view it links directly to the detailed view, with all proper info loading.

**The Issue**

The problem arises if you just type in something like "http://mysite.com/#/campaigns/ANY_ID and *don't* click a link from the list view. The page just loads blank and the renderTemplate is not being called (no alert). The model is loading (getting an alert) and the params.campaign_id is being passed successfully (can be logged into console successfully).

I am thinking this is a router issue but am not sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for taking a look! I can post more info, just let me know what you need in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process that is followed when you go directly to a page is slightly different than if you follow a link. I don't see the links in your template so I'm not 100% sure what is happening, but in general, if you go to the link

```
{{#linkTo myRoute myVar}} A Link {{/linkTo}}
```

The route does not run the `model` function, you just start with `myVar` as your model (but you still execute the `setupController` function).

So for the hardlink to work, you need a `model` function that gathers the information that would have been passed in by the link variable.

Comment: OK, at the moment the link looks like this: {{#linkTo campaigns.campaign keyword.campaign}} which passes the campaign id. The id is still being passed, and when you hit a direct URL the model is firing (under CampaignsCampaign route) which should be collecting the information. Is that the function you mean? Right now we are using: return App.Campaign.find(params.campaign_id);

Comment: yes, that function you declared while extending route is call if and only if you go directly to the page. If you are getting the "Model Firing" alert, and the ID printed to console is correct, then you should look at `App.Campaign.find` and make sure it's behaving as you expect (are you using ember-data or have you rolled your own function?) I'd catch the result of `App.Campaign.find` and examine it.

Comment: I am using ember data and I will try to get the result of that. I should be able to log the result to the console, ya?

Comment: I found out what it was. You were on the right track. The models, while being called, needed to call their overall find()'s to be able to get the singular data for an individual record. I assume this is only because of the way the page is being accessed (direct URL). Thanks very much! :D